# Display an Admob Ad after the opening loader

Tags: android, google-play, admob

Is it allowed by Admob to do what is did in this app (check my screenshots attached below please). There is a loader, after a click button, display an Ad and 1 button & 1 link "tap to continue".
[loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rusOL.png)

[continue button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbEbf.png)

[Ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7pXe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Get the ad loaded up. Then set a listener function that has the command ad.show and the ad will show when the continue button is clicked.

Comment: it's possible to do it, thank you. But are you sure that is allowed by AdMob Policy ?